# Wordpress Homepage not updating

Tags: wordpress

I am facing some problems with my blog's homepage. I am not seeing latest posts on my homepage. When I open the homepage then I saw articles I have posted around 3-4 days ago. Previously I was using cache plugin i.e. WP performance score booster and I think this plugin is causing issue so I removed it and Cloudflare also but still facing problem. Please guide me how to resolve this problem?

Note - When a new users is visiting site then he is getting right information but when returning visitors are visiting site then they are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the plugin that you were using, your returning visitors will need to clear their browser's cache and temporary internet files, close & and reopen their browser, then visit the site again.  The users will then see the updated site content.

Alternatively, you can force not to cache by adding the following meta tag in your header document (before the closing `</head>` tag).

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: It there any way than this ? because telling everyone to clean cache of their browser is bit difficult.